# Firewall blocking mySQL port

Tags: mysql, localhost, nodejs

I am trying to **connect to mysql through node.js** program but it throwing an error.

I am not able to connect to mysql on port 3306.
I already have **apache installed on my PC**.

I have tried http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-18-allow-mysql-server-incoming-request.html
but still it is not working.

Error :

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Handshake.Sequence (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:15:20)
    at new Handshake (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:9:12)
    at Protocol.handshake (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:50)
    at Connection.connect (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:72:18)
    at Connection._implyConnect (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:182:10)
    at Connection.query (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:8)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/1nodeapp/mysql.js:22:18)
    at Server.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at HTTPParser.parser.onIncoming (http.js:2108:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:121:23)
```

Comment: Can you add the error that you're getting?

Comment: @FreudianSlip : Error updated in above question.

Comment: Are you able to actually connect to mysql using the standard mysql client - if so, what's the output of : netstat -nlp | grep -i mysql

Comment: @FreudianSlip : When i have tried sudo netstat -nlp | grep -i mysql i am not getting any response.

Comment: If you're running that command on the machine where mysql is expected to be running, i'd suggest that at this stage, it's not actually started.  From the machine with mysql installed, run a : ps -ef | grep -i mysql

Comment: @FreudianSlip : Yes,i failed to start mysql on my PC.I have started it now and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarise the above:

1) try to connect using the standard mysql client
2) if that works, find out the port it's using

> netstat -nlp | grep -i mysql

so that you can configure the appropriate firewall ports

3) if it didn't work, run

> ps -ef | grep -i mysql | grep -v grep

to discover if mysql is actually running or not
4) if not (as was the case here) start it and repeat if connectivity still fails.

Comment: Issuing command `netstat -nlp | grep -i mysql` passig sudo, allowed me to see right port for mysql and configure firewall rules.